# extract 'column name' on basis of a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table named `Employee` with fields *Id, address, phone_no, salary, date_of_joining* and *stream*. It contains just one row and the fields:

- *Id, salary* and *stream* are populated with values
- whereas  *address, phone_no* and *date_of_joining* contain `NULL` values.

I want the output as the fields that contain `NULL` values, i.e. *address*, *phone_no* and *date_of_joining*. This needs to be executed in Oracle SQL. I am not getting any idea how to go about it.

***Input:***

```
EMPLOYEE                    
Id    Address   phone_no    salary      date_of_joining   stream
101   NULL      NULL        8,00,000    NULL              Big Data
```

***Output:***

```
Address,
phone_no,
date_of_joining
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this explicitly:

```
select 'Id' from t where Id is null union all
select 'Address' from t where Address is null union all
select 'phone_no' from t where phone_no is null union all
select 'salary' from t where salary is null union all
select 'date_of_joining' from t where date_of_joining is null union all
select 'stream' from t where stream is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in this way (same as Gordon's solution but in one record):

```
Select Id,
case when phone_no is null then 'phone_no, ' else '' end || 
case when Address is null then 'Address, ' else '' end ||
case when date_of_joining is null then 'date_of_joining' else '' end as Null_values
from t;
```